# Rails post model for news and blog view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a `post` model and `posts` controller with an attribute `format` so id like to split the views out based on this attribute i.e. `foo.com/blog/xxx` if the format is `blog` and `foo.com/news/xxx` if the format is `news`.

`resources :posts`

```
def index
  @posts = Post.where(draft: 'false').order(publish_date: :desc)
end


def show
  @post = Post.find_by!(slug: params[:id])
end
```

I can easily so something like this for the index view but im unsure about the show route

`get '/new', to: 'posts#news'`

```
def news
  @posts = Post.where(draft: 'false', format: 'news').order(publish_date: :desc)
end
```

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: I thought my question was pretty clear. I want to have one post model but have 2 views, one for news and one for a blog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this way:

Create two different methods to use within your `routes.rb`, they will be inside the only one controller you want to have "`PostsController`", and make a verification of the `params` attribute in every `@post` that pass through the `show` method, something like:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    if @post.format == 'news'
      redirect_to news_index_path
    elsif @post.format == 'blog'
      redirect_to blog_index_path
    end
  end

  def blog_index
  end

  def news_index
  end
  ...
```

Then specify in your `routes.rb` the path to every method, as you made within the `show` method in order to use the `redirect_to` method:

```
  get '/blog/:id',  to: 'posts#blog_index', as: 'blog_index'
  get '/news/:id',  to: 'posts#news_index', as: 'news_index'
```

This is, when you pass a `@post` with the format attribute equal to `blog` you'll be redirected to the `blog_index_path`, which will load the `blog_index` view within your `posts` folder in `app/views/posts`. Something seemed will happen when the `@post.format` is `news`.

```
├── blog_index.html.erb
├── index.html.erb
├── news_index.html.erb
└── show.html.erb

0 directories, 4 files
```

This will have a very little delay and a very quick change in the route, everytime you have to pass from `posts#show` to the next route.

I've made a [repo](https://bitbucket.org/hnhm/test_so), in order you can check how this works.

Answer (score 0):

To indicate a show route, you need to pass id as a parameter in your route.

```
get '/blog/:id' => 'posts#blogs'
```

I guess this is what you are looking for.

Comment: This works fine but it means that unless I add some hack in the controller actions then I can also view the show pages at `/news/foo` as well as `blog/foo`